# Hibernate Mapping Exception in an RCP application

Tags: hibernate, rcp

I get a MappingNotFoundException when trying to use hibernate within my RCP application. I can use hibernate just fine in my Java code. I downloaded the latest stable hibernate release (4.2.2) and included all required jars in a plug-in project using existing jars.  I've implemented the buddy-loading technique in both the referenced plug-in project and my main project. I'm using an annotation based hibernate model with resources mapped to hibernate.cfg.xml. I've implemented my sessionFactory as follows:

```
File configFile = new File("absolute file path of hibernate.cfg.xml here");
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
sessionFactory = cfg.configure(configFile).buildSessionFactory(); //throws error here
```

In my plugin.xml's runtime classpath I have the folder containing my hbm.xml files listed.

An example of my mappings:

```
<mapping resource="hibernate/model/Address.hbm.xml"/>
```

The project is using Maven to resolve hibernate dependencies for Java testing and plug-in dependencies
for the application.

Any insight provided would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

Comment: @Ilya  Are you asking about the structure of the file?

Comment: @Ilya The structure of the file is as follows:  http://pastebin.com/GgxA9Qer                                           All of the Java classes associated with my database was generated through hibernate code generation using EJB3 annotations.